# Не появляется кнопка (адаптпация)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Не появляется кнопка "Найти туры" . Она должна появляться на большом экране . 
Вот строка кода,которая должна появляться. Весь код ниже.

```html
            <button type="submit" class=" form-control border-right-0  btn bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white col-xl-2 d-lg-2 d-md-none d-sm-none">Искать туры</button>
```

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none;            
}
body {
    background: url(123.jpg) repeat-x; /* Параметры фона */
    min-height: 20px; /* Высота слоя */
}

.bg-orange {
  background: #f4a442 !important;
  
}
.sizep {
 width:282;
    height: 60px;
}

.data {
 position:relative;
 width:220px;
 height:60px;
}
.tur {
    position:relative;
 width:280px;
 height:60px;
}
.btn {
 width:196px;
 height:60px;
 position:relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
 display:inline-block;

}
.btn::active {
outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
.formInput > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42px;
    top: 12px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.09;
    color: #9b9b9b;
}
.formControl .formInputPlace {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.formInputPlace > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 margin-left:40px;
}
.formInput>.far {
    z-index: auto;
    top: 21px;
    left: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #059bce;
    transition: top .3s;
    -moz-transition: top .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s;
    -o-transition: top .3s;
}
.formInput .far  {
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.formInput>.fas {
    z-index: auto;
    top: 21px;
    left: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #059bce;
    transition: top .3s;
    -moz-transition: top .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s;
    -o-transition: top .3s;
}
.formInput .fas  {
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.formInputPlace p {
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: margin .3s;
    line-height: inherit;
    color: #333 !important;
    transition: font-size .3s;
    -moz-transition: font-size .3s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .3s;
    -o-transition: font-size .3s;
}
.search  {
  width:362px;
    height: 60px;
}
.form-control {
 position: relative;
 top:280px;
}
 .nav-tabs .nav-item {
  position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
 left:-0.4%;
 top:300px;
 margin-right:15px;
}
.form-control.search .formInputPlace input {
    /* height: 33px; */
    width: 97%;
    /* border: 0; */
    /* color: #333; */
    font: 17px OpenSansRegular;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    top: 5px;
}
.search .formInputPlace .hint {
    color: #a9a9a9 !important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
 position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 85%;
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 60px;
 top:-35px;
}
.city {
 display:inline-block;
 color:blue;
     top: 1px;
    position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
 * {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none;        
  font-size:10px;
}
 .form-control {
 position: relative;
 top:280px;
 left:-1%;
 height:55px;
}
 .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:-11px;
 top:293px;
}
.formInputPlace p {
 font-size:12px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:8px;
 left: 35px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:55px;
}
.btn {
 display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
 .form-row {
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
left:-90px;
width:684px;
}
 .formInputPlace p {
 font-size:9px;
 margin-left: 18px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:8px;
 left: 18px;
 top:3px;
}
btn {
 display:none;
}
.form-control {
 top:10px;
left:1%;
height:30px;
}

 .formInput>.far {
  font-size:15px;
  top:10px;
  left:2px;
 }
  .formInput>.fas {
  font-size:15px;
  top:10px;
  left:2px;
  }
   .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:0%;
 top:20px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:30px;
}
.btn {
 display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
.form-control {
height:30px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.form-row {
 position:relative;
 top:-58px;
left:-15px;
width:545px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:4px;
 left: 16px;
 top:3px;
}
   .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:-2.5%;
 top:0px;
}
 .formInput>.far {
  font-size:10px;
  top:5px;
  left:-1px;
 }
  .formInput>.fas {
  font-size:10px;
  top:5px;
  left:-1px;
  }
   .formInputPlace p {
 font-size:7px;
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-top:8px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:30px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">

<div class="container py-3">


  <div class="tab-content "id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <form>
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0  ">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Город вылета: <p class="city">Новосибирск</p> <span class="font-weight-bold text-primary"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item bg-orange">
      <a class="nav-link text-white bg-orange " style="top:25%;text-transform: uppercase;" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Горячие туры <span class="badge badge-pill text-danger badge-light">-50%</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
        <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 search  col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Страна, курорт или отель  </label>
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
    <input name="search" style="display: inline-block;position: relative;border:0;height: 33px;width: 80%;top: 13px;left:-10px;background: none;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                    <p class="hint">Выберите направление</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Дата вылета  </label>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">С 13.07.2018</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Кол-во ночей </label>
    <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">На 7-8 ночей</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 tur col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Туристы </label>
    <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">2 взрослых</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
            <button type="submit" class=" form-control border-right-0  btn bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white col-xl-2 d-lg-2 d-md-none d-sm-none">Искать туры</button>
   <button type="submit" class=" form-control border-right-0  lupa bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white col-xl-none d-lg-none col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-12 "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите [таблицу](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements), по какому принципу работают классы - `.d-hide` `.d-block`. В вашем случае, для широкого экрана нужно добавить `.d-lg-block`, чтобы показать кнопку:

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none;            
}
body {
    background: url(123.jpg) repeat-x; /* Параметры фона */
    min-height: 20px; /* Высота слоя */
}

.bg-orange {
  background: #f4a442 !important;
  
}
.sizep {
 width:282;
    height: 60px;
}

.data {
 position:relative;
 width:220px;
 height:60px;
}
.tur {
    position:relative;
 width:280px;
 height:60px;
}
.btn {
 width:196px;
 height:60px;
 position:relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
 display:inline-block;

}
.btn::active {
outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
.formInput > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42px;
    top: 12px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.09;
    color: #9b9b9b;
}
.formControl .formInputPlace {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.formInputPlace > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 margin-left:40px;
}
.formInput>.far {
    z-index: auto;
    top: 21px;
    left: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #059bce;
    transition: top .3s;
    -moz-transition: top .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s;
    -o-transition: top .3s;
}
.formInput .far  {
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.formInput>.fas {
    z-index: auto;
    top: 21px;
    left: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #059bce;
    transition: top .3s;
    -moz-transition: top .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s;
    -o-transition: top .3s;
}
.formInput .fas  {
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.formInputPlace p {
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: margin .3s;
    line-height: inherit;
    color: #333 !important;
    transition: font-size .3s;
    -moz-transition: font-size .3s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .3s;
    -o-transition: font-size .3s;
}
.search  {
  width:362px;
    height: 60px;
}
.form-control {
 position: relative;
 top:280px;
}
 .nav-tabs .nav-item {
  position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
 left:-0.4%;
 top:300px;
 margin-right:15px;
}
.form-control.search .formInputPlace input {
    /* height: 33px; */
    width: 97%;
    /* border: 0; */
    /* color: #333; */
    font: 17px OpenSansRegular;
    background: none;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    top: 5px;
}
.search .formInputPlace .hint {
    color: #a9a9a9 !important;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
 position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 85%;
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 60px;
 top:-35px;
}
.city {
 display:inline-block;
 color:blue;
     top: 1px;
    position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
 * {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none;        
  font-size:10px;
}
 .form-control {
 position: relative;
 top:280px;
 left:-1%;
 height:55px;
}
 .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:-11px;
 top:293px;
}
.formInputPlace p {
 font-size:12px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:8px;
 left: 35px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:55px;
}
.btn {
 display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
 .form-row {
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
left:-90px;
width:684px;
}
 .formInputPlace p {
 font-size:9px;
 margin-left: 18px;
 margin-top:10px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:8px;
 left: 18px;
 top:3px;
}
btn {
 display:none;
}
.form-control {
 top:10px;
left:1%;
height:30px;
}

 .formInput>.far {
  font-size:15px;
  top:10px;
  left:2px;
 }
  .formInput>.fas {
  font-size:15px;
  top:10px;
  left:2px;
  }
   .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:0%;
 top:20px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:30px;
}
.btn {
 display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:568px) {
.form-control {
height:30px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.form-row {
 position:relative;
 top:-58px;
left:-15px;
width:545px;
}
.formInput > label {
 font-size:4px;
 left: 16px;
 top:3px;
}
   .nav-tabs .nav-item {
 left:-2.5%;
 top:0px;
}
 .formInput>.far {
  font-size:10px;
  top:5px;
  left:-1px;
 }
  .formInput>.fas {
  font-size:10px;
  top:5px;
  left:-1px;
  }
   .formInputPlace p {
 font-size:7px;
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-top:8px;
}
.lupa {
  width:196px;
 height:30px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">

<div class="container py-3">


  <div class="tab-content "id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <form>
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0  ">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Город вылета: <p class="city">Новосибирск</p> <span class="font-weight-bold text-primary"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item bg-orange">
      <a class="nav-link text-white bg-orange " style="top:25%;text-transform: uppercase;" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Горячие туры <span class="badge badge-pill text-danger badge-light">-50%</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
        <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 search  col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Страна, курорт или отель  </label>
    <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
    <input name="search" style="display: inline-block;position: relative;border:0;height: 33px;width: 80%;top: 13px;left:-10px;background: none;text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                    <p class="hint">Выберите направление</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Дата вылета  </label>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">С 13.07.2018</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Кол-во ночей </label>
    <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">На 7-8 ночей</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 tur col-lg-3 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Туристы </label>
    <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">2 взрослых</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
            <button type="submit" class=" form-control border-right-0  btn bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white col-xl-2 d-lg-2 d-md-none d-sm-none d-lg-block">Искать туры</button>
   <button type="submit" class=" form-control border-right-0  lupa bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white col-xl-none d-lg-none col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-12 "><i class="fas fa-search" style="font-size:20px;"></i></button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```